# How do I limit the speed of a particular usb device?

Tags: 16.04, usb

I have a new machine that uses xhci-hcd (usb 3.0), but some USB devices are not working.

I want to try to limit the speed to usb 2.0. Is it possible?

Thanks.

Update:

- Machine: Dell Optiplex 3040
- Ubuntu 16.04 64bits
- Output of lsusb

`Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 413c:301a Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2107 Dell Computer Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0525:a4a2 Netchip Technology, Inc. Linux-USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1c8a:3012
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub`

The Device with no name is a Sweda thermal receipt printer. This is the device not working. Also the Netchip device is not working properly (still investigating).

Update 2 - dmesg output:

`[  162.592638] usb 1-10: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  165.982686] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[  166.125747] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1c8a, idProduct=3012
[  166.125752] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=6
[  166.125755] usb 1-1: Product: Printer Class 
[  166.125757] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: SAM4S CORP.
[  166.125759] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 0000000000002
[  166.127973] usblp 1-1:1.0: usblp0: USB Bidirectional printer dev 6 if 0 alt 0 proto 2 vid 0x1C8A pid 0x3012`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Would you be so kind as to [edit] your post to include the make and model of your new machine,  the devices that are not working and the output of `lsusb` with the devices attached? Thank you for helping us help you! You may find [these guidelines](http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask) useful in determining how to best obtain useful answers.

Comment: Related: https://www.systutorials.com/qa/1908/how-to-force-a-usb-3-0-port-to-work-in-usb-2-0-mode-in-linux

Comment: Tried the instructions on the link, but it did not make the usb device work. Thanks.

Comment: Do you get the same result (PCI ID) on the Sweda Thermal Receipt Printer if you connect it to a different port?  The vendor ID on that device [maps to TSF5 Corporation](http://pciids.sourceforge.net/v2.2/pci.ids) and I'm wondering if it's a communications failure or simply a re-branding.

Comment: It's a re-branding. The same printer exists with the SAM4S brand. dmesg says Manufacturer: SAM4S CORP.